# Google Maps, coldfusion, dynamic markers and info, opening infowindow with link on page

Tags: google-maps-api-3, coldfusion

I have a custom google map which i have added styling to, its an event map with dynamic markers, i have got the map working where it loads all the dynamic markers and info, on my page there are results underneath the map, i would like to be able to click on a link in the results which will open the relevant infowindow on the map. I have been using Raymond Camdens demo which is from this [article](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/4/13/Simple-introduction-to-Google-Maps-Part-2--Markers), i cannot get the last part to work with the links on the page(i had to take the geocoding part of the script out as i dont need it to geocode addresses, im using coordinates.)

Here is my code:

```
var map;

var lastinfowindow;

function initialize() {


    // Create an array of styles.
  var styles = [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#0b9cc1" },
        { saturation: -20 }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { lightness: 100 },
        { visibility: "simplified" }
      ]
    },{
      featureType: "administrative.country",
      elementType: "labels",
      stylers: [
        { visibility: "on" }
      ]
    },

    { featureType: "water", 
     elementType: "geometry", 
    stylers: [ { visibility: "on" }, { lightness: -10 }] },
    { featureType: "poi", 
    stylers: [ { visibility: "on" } ] }

  ];

  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: "Styled Map"}); 





    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -90);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

    var image = 'sp-mark.png';



   latLng = new google.maps.LatLng ('23.00593', '12.65287');
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: LatLng,
                title: 'Event 1 - 38',
                icon:image
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h3 class=maph3>Event 1</h3><p>Location: here</p>"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            marker.gigid = 38;
            marker.infowindow = infowindow;
            markers[markers.length] = marker;

   latLng = new google.maps.LatLng ('57.19173', '-1.7083');
            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: LatLng,
                title: 'Event 2 - 30',
                icon:image
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h3 class=maph3>Event 2</h3><p>Location: here</p>"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            marker.gigid = 30;
            marker.infowindow = infowindow;
            markers[markers.length] = marker;

   latLng = new google.maps.LatLng ('56.98083', '1.30056');
            var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: LatLng,
                title: 'Event 3 - 32',
                icon:image
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h3 class=maph3>Event 3</h3><p>Location: here, Ibiza</p>"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            marker.gigid = 32;
            marker.infowindow = infowindow;
            markers[markers.length] = marker;

   latLng = new google.maps.LatLng ('58.96', '1.39861');
            var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: LatLng,
                title: 'Event 4 - 41',
                icon:image
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h3 class=maph3>Event 4</h3><p>Location: here</p>"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            marker.gigid = 41;
            marker.infowindow = infowindow;
            markers[markers.length] = marker;

   latLng = new google.maps.LatLng ('-43.92528', '28.42389');
            var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: LatLng,
                title: 'Event 5 - 47',
                icon:image
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h3 class=maph3>Event 5</h3><p>Location: Here</p>"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
             infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            marker.gigid = 47;
            marker.infowindow = infowindow;
            markers[markers.length] = marker;


    //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
     map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
     map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

    $(".order").click(function() {
        var thisgig = $(this).data("gigid");
        for(var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
            if(markers[i].gigid == thisgig) {
                console.log("found my match");
                //get the latlong
                if(lastinfowindow instanceof google.maps.InfoWindow) lastinfowindow.close();
                console.dir(markers[i]);
                map.panTo(markers[i].getPosition());
                markers[i].infowindow.open(map, markers[i]);
                lastinfowindow = markers[i].infowindow;
            }
        }
    });



}
```

here is the body section where the links will go:

```
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<div id="orders">

    <p class="order" data-gigid="38">
    <b>Order 38</b><br/>
    Event 1
    </p>

    <p class="order" data-gigid="30">
    <b>Order 30</b><br/>
    Event 2
    </p>

    <p class="order" data-gigid="32">
    <b>Order 32</b><br/>
    Event 3
    </p>

    <p class="order" data-gigid="41">
    <b>Order 41</b><br/>
    Event 4
    </p>

    <p class="order" data-gigid="47">
    <b>Order 47</b><br/>
    Event 5
    </p>

</div>

</body>
```

Please can someone help me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What error are you seeing when you execute your code? You told it's not working, but not what's happening. Do you have the page online somewhere that we could see what's going on?

Comment: Yes its not working, i dont get an error it is just a blank map, i dont have it online at the moment but the code above just needs to be pasted on a webpage with a link to jquery and tge google maps script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps will generally fail to load if you have any javascript errors in your page.  You have many.

You have a syntax error here:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h3 class=maph3>Event 4</h3><p>Location: here</p>
            });
```

Should be:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h3 class=maph3>Event 4</h3><p>Location: here</p>"
            });
```

LatLng takes two floats, not two strings:

```
latLng = new google.maps.LatLng ('23.00593', '12.65287');
```

Javascript is case-sensitive.  So when you say:

```
latLng = new google.maps.LatLng ('23.00593', '12.65287');
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                ...
                position: LatLng
            });
```

It doesn't recognise **LatLng** because your variable was called **latLng**

The problem here:

```
marker.gigid = 38;
```

is that you don't have a variable called marker; you have a variable called marker1:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: LatLng,
                title: 'Event 1 - 38',
                icon:image
            });
```

For completeness, here's how one of your markers should be done (there are better ways, but this should work):
latLng = new google.maps.LatLng (23.00593,12.65287);
            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: latLng ,
                title: 'Event 1 - 38',
                icon:image
            });

```
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "<h3 class=maph3>Event 1</h3><p>Location: here</p>"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
         infowindow.open(map,marker1);
        });

        marker1.gigid = 38;
        marker1.infowindow = infowindow;
        markers[markers.length] = marker1;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, it still does not help my issue, please can someone help with this, it has something to do with this line marker.gigid = 30 on each result and also the jquery.

Comment: I have just edited the code above to include the quotation mark i left out

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, should the same apply to infowindow:

Comment: var infowindow should be var infowindow1?

Comment: Thanks Duncan, sorry to worry  you again, the map is working now, loading all markers and relevant info for the markers, the thing that is not working is when the link gets clicked, nothing opens, is there something wrong with the jquery script that starts with: $(".order").click(function() {

Comment: i mean the link that is wrapped in the p tag in the body

Comment: that's a whole other question I think

Comment: Ok i will ask another question

Comment: here is a link to the other question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649006/coldfusion-google-maps-and-jquery)